# R calculate hours after midnight

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I would like to use R to calculate the time difference between two military time (e.g., 13:00 and 7:00) in R. supposed I have the following data table:

| id | start.time | end.time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18:00 | 2:00 |
| 2 | 18:00 | 20:00 |
| 3 | 2:00 | 4:00 |

---

I would like to calculate the time difference between start.time and end.time. I expect my result to be as follow:

| id | start.time | end.time | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18:00 | 2:00 | 8 |
| 2 | 18:00 | 20:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2:00 | 4:00 | 2 |

---

**`as.POSIXct()` & `difftime()`**
I have tried to use `as.posixct(start.time, format = '%H:%M')` and `as.POSIXct(end.time, format = '%H:%M')` to turn the start.time and end.time into a datetime class, and use `difftime()` to find the time difference between them. This would only work for 2 & 3. For the first one, the `as.POSIXct()` argument turns all time into the same date and so the difference between them does not equal 8.

*My question is: Is there a code that can take into account all of these scenarios?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert your hours into R POSIXct object, then add one day to `end.time` if it is earlier than `start.time`. Finally use `difftime` to calculate their difference in hours and remove any unwanted columns (the final `select` function).

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(ends_with("time"), ~as.POSIXct(.x, format = '%H:%M'), .names = "{.col}2"),
              end.time2 = if_else(end.time2 < start.time2, end.time2 + 1*60*60*24, end.time2),
              difftime = difftime(end.time2, start.time2)) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("2"))

  id start.time end.time difftime
1  1      18:00     2:00  8 hours
2  2      18:00    20:00  2 hours
3  3       2:00     4:00  2 hours
```

Comment: Hi Benson, Thank you for your answer. Your way works best with my current project.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will achieve what you are looking for, although it may be hard to generalize.

```
data<-data.frame(
  id=c(1,2,3),
  start.time=c("18:00","18:00","2:00"),
  end.time=c("2:00","20:00","4:00")
)
library(tidyverse)
data<-mutate(data,
             start.time=as.numeric(gsub("\\:.*","",start.time)),
             end.time=as.numeric(gsub("\\:.*","",end.time)),
             diff=ifelse(end.time>start.time,end.time-start.time,
                         (24-start.time)+end.time))
```

Where you simply subtract `end.time` from `start.time` if `end.time` is larger. If `start.time` is larger, then subtract `start.time` from 24 first and then add `end.time`. This is contingent on the minutes being inconsequential, since I've used `gsub()` to remove everything after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 24*60^2 seconds (one day) to those date-times where the row differences are less than zero. Since the result will be seconds, we divide it by `60^2`. `matrixStats::rowDiffs` will be lightning fast here.

```
> transform(dat, 
+           diff=sapply(dat[2:3], as.POSIXct, format='%H:%M') |>
+             {\(.) {
+               nw_dy <- matrixStats::rowDiffs(.) < 0
+               .[nw_dy, 2] <- .[nw_dy, 2] + 24*60^2
+               unname(.)
+             }}() |>
+             matrixStats::rowDiffs()/60^2)
  id start.time end.time diff
1  1      18:00     2:00    8
2  2      18:00    20:00    2
3  3       2:00     4:00    2
```

Without *matrixStats*, you can do the following, which, of course, will be slower:

```
> transform(dat, 
+           diff=sapply(dat[2:3], as.POSIXct, format='%H:%M') |>
+             {\(.) {
+               nw_dy <- .[, 'end.time'] - .[, 'start.time'] < 0
+               .[nw_dy, 2] <- .[nw_dy, 2] + 24*60^2
+               unname(.)
+             }}() |>
+             apply(1, diff)/60^2)
  id start.time end.time diff
1  1      18:00     2:00    8
2  2      18:00    20:00    2
3  3       2:00     4:00    2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(id = 1:3, start.time = c("18:00", "18:00", "2:00"
), end.time = c("2:00", "20:00", "4:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```